# Error when trying to run Node.js Ubuntu project in Mac:

Tags: mysql, node.js, sqlite, express

I am working with Node.js, Express.js and sqlite3 to create a small website.
I have developed my project in Ubuntu and I have been trying to get it to work in Mac also.

But after I svn checkout from my repository the folder of the project, and try to run my app.js file I get the following error:

```
module.js:356
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                           ^
 Error: dlopen(/Users/cs205g1s13/BS/baby_skype_less/node_modules/sqlite3/build/Release/node_sqlite3.node, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/cs205g1s13/BS/baby_skype_less/node_modules/sqlite3/build/Release/node_sqlite3.node: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/cs205g1s13/BS/baby_skype_less/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:1:104)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

The website works fine on Ubuntu. And also, the Mac computer has Node.js, sqlite3. Any help of why this is happening would be appreciated.

---

I removed the node_modules from my svn repository, and svn checkout my project folder into a mac computer. When I do npm install sqlite3 I get the following errors:

```
$ npm install sqlite3

npm WARN package.json application-name@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sqlite3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sqlite3
```

> sqlite3@2.1.7 install /Users/cs205g1s13/BS/playing/node_modules/sqlite3
>   node-gyp rebuild

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp", line 15, in <module>
import gyp
File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
import gyp.input
File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 15, in <module>
import multiprocessing
ImportError: No module named multiprocessing
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:415:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:784:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-          gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/cs205g1s13/BS/playing/node_modules/sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.9.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! sqlite3@2.1.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@2.1.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the sqlite3 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sqlite3
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "sqlite3"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/cs205g1s13/BS/playing
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.4
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cs205g1s13/BS/playing/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check in your node_modules folder into svn? Don't do that. To fix it, run `npm rebuild` on your Ubuntu box. sqlite uses extensions that must be compiled on the host platform.

Comment: After I do the npm rebuild in Ubuntu should I push the node_modules folder into the repository or not?

Comment: No. svn is for source code for your project. node_modules is installed third party software. Check your package.json file into svn but leave node_modules out.

Comment: I followed your instructions and everything works fine for all my other modules, but not for sqlite3

Comment: That looks like you might not have the right python version, but I don't know the details you need off the top of my head.